# Rename Sketchup Component meshes for Unity

Tags: unity, entity-component, sketchup

When i create a component in Sketchup and i export it to Unity, the component structure is always:
[image]

- Component_Name
- - MeshX

How can i avoid having the component name as an empty parent and just set it for the mesh itself? (i want a single object)

Comment: Have you tried unparenting the mesh and saving it as its own prefab?

Comment: That's what i'm doing but i want to get it imported properly rather than doing hacks :(

Comment: In what way is this improper? A sketchup file can contain multiple meshes, so it's reasonable for Unity to import it as a hierarchy rather than a single mesh object. If it failed to do that, importing just a single object instead, and you later added multiple meshes to the sketchup file and re-imported, you could end up with unwanted results where the second mesh shows up everywhere you were using the first mesh, even if you only wanted to use one or the other. The hierarchy lets you tell Unity "I want just this one mesh from the file here" vs "I want all the meshes from the file here"

Comment: Sketchup file can contain multiple meshes yes, that's why components & groups exist, i expect to name those meshes separately.
You're also duplicating the work. you first name them in sketchup to have them in  order, and then you also need to name them again in unity.  There must be a better way.